# Открыть файл по нажатию на ссылку или кнопку

Tags: php, javascript, html

Нужно по нажатию на кнопку или ссылку открывать файл. То есть, есть ссылка

```
<a href='ссылка на файл'>Открыть файл</a>
```

По нажатию на неё нужно, чтобы открывался файл, который находится по ссылке. Чтоб открывался на в браузере, а в самой винде. То есть, если это xls - то в excel, doc - word и так далее. Подскажите, это возможно сделать?

Comment: Нет, это невозможно сделать, т.к. браузер может только дать скачать вам файл по HTTP-протоколу, после чего его можно будет открыть.

Comment: Может у вас есть идеи, как можно реализовать редактирование xls файла? Думал давать пользователю возможность просто открывать файл по нажатию на ссылку или кнопку и чтоб редактировал что хотел. А коль так...

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать сделать ссылку на скрипт загрузки,

`<a href='download_file.php?file_id=123'>Открыть файл</a>`

А в самом скрипте в зависимости от переданного id отдавать файл с нужными заголовками, например для MS Word

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");
echo $file_content;
exit;
```

Comment: Вы сами пробовали? Что это даст в итоге?

Comment: То же самое - скачивание файла